# Kivy Language - How to get the text from MDTextField in kivy language (.kv file)

Tags: python, kivy-language, kivymd

so i am creating this simple YouTube downloader app that has 3 different screens, main, MP3 Download screen, and the MP4 Download screen, both last screens have a MDTextField where the user should paste the YouTube video URL and i should get that MDTextField value and pass it to the download function in main.py file (see the codes below), but i don't know how to do that, if anyone can help i would be so much grateful and if you need any further explanation or more details than the details i provided i am here because i did my best to show all my work.

Thanks in advance.

main.py:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager  
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import requests
import youtube_dl

Window.size = (350, 600)

class MainApp(MDApp):
    global screen_manager
    screen_manager = ScreenManager()

    def build(self):
        self.title = "Yahiatube"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'BlueGray'

        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("mainScreen.kv"))
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("MP3Screen.kv"))
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("MP4Screen.kv"))

        return screen_manager

    def check_video_url(video_id):
        checker_url = "https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url="
        video_url = checker_url + video_id
        request = requests.get(video_url)
        return request.status_code == 200


#work on this one
    def download_mp3(variable):
        print('working')
        
    def download_mp4(variable):
        print('working')


    def change_screen(self, screen):
        screen_manager.current = screen


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

mainScreen.kv

```
MDScreen:
    name: "MainScreen"
    md_bg_color: [64/255, 66/255, 88/255, 1]

    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "DOWNLOAD MP3"
        font_size : 20
        md_bg_color: 0,0,0,1
        pos : 85, 370
        width : 150
        on_press : app.change_screen("MP3Screen")

    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "DOWNLOAD MP4"
        font_size: 20
        md_bg_color: 0,0,0,1
        pos : 85, 320
        width: 150
        on_press : app.change_screen("MP4Screen")
```

MP3Screen.kv:

```
MDScreen:
    name: "MP3Screen"
    md_bg_color: [64/255, 66/255, 88/255, 1]

    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "Download"
        font_size : 20
        md_bg_color: 0,0,0,1
        pos_hint : {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}
        width : 150
        on_press : app.download_mp3()

    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "GO BACK"
        font_size : 20
        md_bg_color : 0,0,0,1
        pos_hint : {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .52}
        width: 150
        on_press: app.change_screen("MainScreen")


    MDTextField:
        id: data
        hint_text: "Paste the YouTube video URL Here"
        pos_hint: {"center_x":.5,"center_y":.7}
        width: 300
        size_hint : None,None
        font_size : "15dp"
        line_color_focus : 0/255,0/255,0/255,1
        mode : "rectangle"
        pos : 93,280
```

MP4Screen.kv:

```
MDScreen:
    name: "MP4Screen"
    md_bg_color: [64/255, 66/255, 88/255, 1]

    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "Download"
        font_size : 20
        md_bg_color: 0,0,0,1
        pos_hint : {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .6}
        width : 150
        on_press : app.download_mp4()

    MDRaisedButton:
        text: "GO BACK"
        font_size : 20
        md_bg_color : 0,0,0,1
        pos_hint : {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .52}
        width: 150
        on_press: app.change_screen("MainScreen")

    MDTextField:
        id: data
        hint_text: "Paste the YouTube video URL Here"
        pos_hint: {"center_x":.5,"center_y":.7}
        width: 300
        size_hint : None,None
        font_size : "15dp"
        line_color_focus : 0/255,0/255,0/255,1
        mode : "rectangle"
        pos : 93,280
```

Comment: Try using its `text` property.

Comment: @ApuCoder it gave me back a kind of its address in the memory or something : '<__main__.MainApp object at 0x7f49dce05700>'

Comment: def download_mp3(variable) should be def download_mp3(self, variable, *args)  and for your callback try app.download_mp4(data.text).  you can try printing the variables and also the type() of the variables to see what you are getting passed in.

Comment: @Mark thank you very much sir, you solved my problem, would you please write it as an answer and i will validate it as the answer, may someone face the same problem in the future

Comment: ok, thanks for following up.  I hope I have explained it well enough below.  This kind of question was a big tripping point for me when I was first leaning Kivy, so I think it is important to put the help out here in various forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In class methods, a reference **self** is passed automatically so you need to have that argument.

Python has syntax for absorbing extra positional arguments and extra keyword arguments sent to a function or method that were not in its signature.

```
def download_mp3(self, variable, *args):
    print(f"working {variable} ; {args}")
    
def download_mp4(self, variable, *args):
    print(f"working {variable} ; {args}")
```

the kivy language (.kv files) ids are not directly available in the Python code but they are available within the .kv object so they can be passed like this.

```
app.download_mp4(data.text)  # where data is an id of another widget
```

in context:

```
MDTextField:
    id: data
    hint_text: "Paste the YouTube video URL Here"

MDRaisedButton:
    text: "Download"
    on_press : app.download_mp4(data.text)
```

If a person decides to bind a method to a Button using the Python code instead of the .kv file then a reference to the button will automatically be passed to the method.  That is where the *args is important in the signature because it can be absorbed and you avoid raising an Exception.